# Prove the sequence is bounded above by $3$ and below by $\frac{3}{5}$

Tags: analysis

$\dfrac{3n}{n+4}$ where $n$ is an element of the natural numbers.

I used calculus to find my supposed surprema and infimum. But I am having a difficult time proving they are infimum and suprema. I am assuming to prove the infimum and suprema you have to make a inequality about the sequence, i.e.

$\dfrac{3n}{n+4} + 3 > \epsilon$

But I am having a hard time understanding also the infimum

$\epsilon < \dfrac{3n}{n+4} - \dfrac{3}{5}$

Please help

Comment: Try proving by contradiction.  Suppose that there is an n such that $3/5 > 3n/(n+4)$ and the same thing for the upper bound.

Comment: HINT: $$\frac{3n}{n+4} = 3 - \frac{12}{n+4}$$

Comment: Who said to find supremum and infimum? If someone says "bounded above by $3$," all they mean is that the $n$th term is never greater than $3$. Likewise, bounded below by $3/5$ means only the $n$th term is always greater than $3/5.$ No epsilons need apply.

Comment: the question in my assignment wants me to prove it's a infimum or suprema

Answer (score 0):

$$\frac{n}{n+4}=\frac{n+4-4}{n+4}=1-\frac{4}{n+4}$$
Now, as $n$ increases, $n+4$ also increases, so $\frac{1}{n+4}$ decreases, and $\frac{-4}{n+4}$ increases.

However, $\frac{-4}{n+4}$ is negative for all $n\ge 0$, so it is increasing and negative, with limit $0$.  Hence by taking $n$ large enough, you can make $\frac{-4}{n+4}$ as close to zero as you want.  Now do some algebra to see how big $n$ has to be to make $\frac{3n}{n+4}>\frac{3}{5}$.

Comment: i am not sure how this proves it's an infimum or suprema